# How do I match ids?

Tags: ruby

I have 3 controllers which are 'client_workouts', 'client' and 'trainer'. In the client_workouts controller I want to have a link which directs you to the 'client/:id' page. But it doesn't seem to work?

```
    <td><%= link_to client_workout.client_name, 'client' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to client_workout.trainer, 'trainer' %></td>
    <td><%= client_workout.duration_mins %></td>
    <td><%= client_workout.date_of_workout %></td>
    <td><%= client_workout.paid_amount %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', client_workout %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_workout_path(client_workout) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', client_workout, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Do I have to match the id's???

Comment: you need need set pass parameter in url like     `<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', client_workout_path(client.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>`

Comment: Do you mean `<%= link_to 'Show', client_workout_path(client_workout) %>`?

Comment: <td><%= link_to client_workout.client_name, 'client' %></td> I mean this line. I want it to direct to the client/:id page I made in a different controller.

Comment: I made some scaffold forms there in my 'clients'  and I want it to match the one's in my 'client_workouts'

Comment: For example, when I click the name from the 'client_workouts' index, it'll direct me to the 'clients/:id' page which has the client's profile.

Comment: Did you try this ? This should work if path is correct and client_workout is an object `<td><%= link_to client_workout.client_name, client_path(client_workout.id) %></td>`

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go client/:id i.e. show action

you need to send client id as a parameter

```
   <td><%= link_to client_workout.client_name, client_path(client_workout) %></td>
```

Comment: It's generally bad form to put `id` in the various `_path` methods. Leaving `client_workout` in there is sufficient and respects any `to_param` overrides that might be in place.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, and I always prefer good idea and updated the answer :)